# Exported excel from PHP getting errors

Tags: javascript, php, excel

I'm troubleshooting an Excel export issue with the below code. I get this error when I open the exported file:

> The file format and extension of '`filename.xls`' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

Any support appreciated!

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
 
        var month_nw = '<?php echo $main_data->month; ?>';
 
        var file_type = month_nw+'-Pay Sheet';
 
        var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
        tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        tab_text = tab_text + '<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/global/css/default_print.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
 
        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>EPF REPORT</x:Name>';
 
        tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
 
        tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
        tab_text = tab_text + $('#print_btn_1').html();
        tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';
 
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
 
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
 
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                    type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                });
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, ''+file_type+'.xls');
            }
        } else {
            $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
            $('#test').attr('download',''+file_type+'.xls');
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: try [ file > save as > (some options...) ] does it work?